# about aura datatable cellattributes

Tags: aura, datatable

I want to approach the following requirement, it is possible to change a valor displayed in a field of the row of datatable regards um determinate valor received, for example if the field has a 1 i want to show  "active" or 2 "inactive" I try this code but it didn't function

[image]

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <!-- Imports 
<aura:import library="lightningcomponentdemo:mockdataFaker" property="mockdataLibrary"/>-->

<!-- attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>

<!-- handlers-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>


<!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
<div style="height: 300px">
    <lightning:datatable
            keyField="id"
            data="{! v.data }"
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true"
            onsort="{!c.handleSort}"/>
            
</div>
```

</aura:component>

controller

```
({

init: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.setColumns(cmp);
    helper.setData(cmp);
},

handleSort: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.handleSort(cmp, event);
}})
```

Helper

```
({
COLUMNS: [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' },
    { label: 'Age',  fieldName: 'age', type: 'number', sortable: true, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },},
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' },
    { label: 'status', fieldName: 'status', type: 'text',  typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'status' } }, cellAttributes: { title: { fieldName: 'status' } },
  type: function(value) {
        if (value === '1') { return 'Active';} else if (value === '2') {return 'Inactive';} else {return '';}}}],

DATA: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Billy Simonns',    age: 40, email: 'billy@salesforce.com' , status: '1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Kelsey Denesik',   age: 35, email: 'kelsey@salesforce.com', status: '2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Kyle Ruecker',     age: 50, email: 'kyle@salesforce.com' , status: '1'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Krystina Kerluke', age: 37, email: 'krystina@salesforce.com', status: '2'},
],

setColumns: function(cmp) {
    cmp.set('v.columns', this.COLUMNS);
},

setData: function(cmp) {
    
    cmp.set('v.data', this.DATA);
},

// Used to sort the 'Age' column
sortBy: function(field, reverse, primer) {
    var key = primer
        ? function(x) {
              return primer(x[field]);
          }
        : function(x) {
              return x[field];
          };

    return function(a, b) {
        a = key(a);
        b = key(b);
        return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    };
},

handleSort: function(cmp, event) {
    var sortedBy = event.getParam('fieldName');
    var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');

    var cloneData = this.DATA.slice(0);
    cloneData.sort((this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1)));
    
    cmp.set('v.data', cloneData);
    cmp.set('v.sortDirection', sortDirection);
    cmp.set('v.sortedBy', sortedBy);
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your helper function "setData", before you set the data to the component, edit it there.

For example, something like this:

```
setData: function(cmp) {
    this.DATA.forEach(function(value){
        value.originalStatus = value.orignalStatus||value.status;  //Save old value
        if (value.originalStatus === '1')
            value.status = 'Active';
        else if (value.originalStatus === '2')
            value.status = 'Inactive';
        else
            value.status = '';
    });

    cmp.set('v.data', this.DATA);
},
```

There may be typos in there, and it is better to not have to replace the value if possible, but this gives you the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, you need to transform your data to match:

```
const labels = [null, 'Active', 'Inactive'];
const transform = (record) => ({ ...record, statusLabel: labels[record.status] });
this.DATA = this.DATA.map(transform);
```

And update the column data accordingly:

```
{ label: 'status', fieldName: 'statusLabel', type: 'text' },
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!